# ZBAR read static UIImage (No Camera preview)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, zbar-sdk

Im building an application for IPad and I am using ZBar.

The image containing the barcode data is a `UIImage` called `TempUIImage`.  How can I use ZBar to detect the value of the barcode and it's location.

Note: I don't want want  the camera preview at all as the `TempUIImage` is an `UIImage` that should be taken from another application.

Comment: I also have this issue.. can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ZBarImageScanner` class. 
Here there is a complete documentation [ZBarImageScanner](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/ZBarImageScanner.html)

Here there is an example on how to use it (I don't tested it on device):

```
ZBarImageScanner *scanner = [[ZBarImageScanner alloc]init];
NSInteger resultsnumber = [scanner scanImage:yourUIImage];
if(resultsnumber > 0){
    ZBarSymbolSet *results = scanner.results;
    //do whatever u want with results!!!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i was also facing this issue in one of my project, i solved the issue by making an object of ZBarImageScanner as

```
ZBarImageScanner *scanner
```

See my answer at [Scaning static UIImage using ios ZBar SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21988335/1556386) for details