# Is it possible to decode QRCode image to value

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, qr-code

I'm looking for code which help me to convert QRCode from image. there is very easy way with `AVFoundation` to scan QR Code with help of camera. But if I want to get encoded qr string from UIImage is there any way to do so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822521/scaning-static-uiimage-using-ios-zbar-sdk

Comment: Thnaks you for Quick reply. yes i appreciate you answer but without zbar sdk is it possible to do so ? like with native ios code only ?

Comment: I doubt it will be possible using native code. I cannot find a way as far as I have searched

Comment: @ZeMoon by the way thanks, lets wait for few people to see question , may i get my proper answer. i will go with your solution if i could not find any alternative ans.

Answer (score 9):

**Native solution:**
As far as I know you can scan QR from video since iOS 7. (See other answers)
But scanning from image appeared only in iOS 8.

See [`CIQRCodeFeature`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CIQRCodeFeature/index.html)

and [this shinobicontrols tutorial](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2014/08/05/ios8-day-by-day-day-13-coreimage-detectors)

**third party libs:**
For example [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 5):

```
CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode context:nil options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh}];
if (detector)  {
  NSArray* featuresR = [detector featuresInImage:scannedImg.CIImage];
  NSString* decodeR;
  for (CIQRCodeFeature* featureR in featuresR)  {
    NSLog(@"decode %@ ",featureR.messageString);
    decodeR = featureR.messageString;
  }
}
```

Comment: After I tried many times, I found that this code only works for original qrcode image. If I take a new photo for qrcode image, it will detect the new image failed with a high rate.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? that the recognition is not as expected?

Comment: Yes, it works for [![WechatIMG27.jpg](https://s3.postimg.org/tiopewwer/Wechat_IMG27.jpg)](https://postimg.org/image/bsn0tvitr/) , but not for [![WechatIMG28.jpg](https://s14.postimg.org/n0v6iguk1/Wechat_IMG28.jpg)](https://postimg.org/image/n0v6igujx/)

Answer (score 3):

### EDIT:

This answer describes how to scan for QR codes in the input from the camera. That's not what the OP asked. The OP asked about scanning a still image. See @DanSkeel's answer for that.

I'm leaving this answer since it is still useful.

---

It is indeed possible. Apple added an API for detecting barcodes in iOS 7.

Your search terms are AVCaptureMetadataOutput, AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject.

It's a little involved. You have to create a AVCaptureSession, find the camera and attach it as a capture device, and then create an AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and tell it to monitor for specific types of bar codes (in your case AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode).

There is a sample project by shinobicontrols that shows how to do it. Go to this link:

[**shinobicontrols - Introducing iOS7 Day-by-Day**](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2013/09/19/introducing-ios7-day-by-day)

The project you want is Day 16: Decoding QR codes.

Note that Apple's bar code reading API can read a couple of dozen types of barcodes. You tell it which types you are interested in. I modified the demo project to detect ALL supported barcodes. It was able to detect UPC codes, US postal barcodes, QR codes, and lots of others that I was able to find and test.

BTW, that's a great site. Lots of very helpful little demos of new APIs Apple introduced in iOS 7 there.

EDIT:

Ok, I guess I exaggerated. Apple's code can decode the following barcode formats (I count 10, which is hardly "dozens"...)

```
AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode,
AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode
```

Comment: He asked about QR code on UIImage, not from camera.

Comment: @DanSkeel, so he did. I did not notice that. It might be possible to configure an AVCaptureSession with a still image as the source. Seems like Apple should offer an API for still images as well.

Answer (score 2):

We use https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC which supports every kind of barcode including QR. It's a pure Objective-C version of  ZXing which is now java only.

Comment: ahwulf, note that starting in iOS 7, Apple added barcode reading support directly to the OS. (See my answer)

Comment: I know, it's not nearly as broad as this library, we look at pretty obscure barcodes sometimes that Apple doesn't cover.

Comment: @ahwulf I am using Zxing Swift version, it reading only code128 format from the images, other qr codes it's not reading from images. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting for people who have tried above answers but that doesn't worked for them. This worked for me.

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode context:context options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh}];
CIImage *imageQRCode = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:<YourImageToBeRead>.CGImage];
NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:imageQRCode];
        CIQRCodeFeature *feature = [features firstObject];

NSString *result = feature.messageString;
```